# Using XSL transformation with XML to HTML - output is blank

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am a novice to XML and XSL to convert to HTML. I have created my XML and XSL but my output is blank. I think it has something to do with the nodes not being matched? But I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wci="http://www.jda.com/taglibs/wci" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt">
<xsl:template match="Privacy">      
<xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lowercase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//ContentSettings/LenovoCodeBase">
<c:if><xsl:attribute name="test">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">${empty LenovoCodeBase}</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
<c:set var="LenovoCodeBase" scope="request">
<xsl:attribute name="value">
<xsl:value-of select="//ContentSettings/LenovoCodeBase"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</c:set>
</c:if>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<c:if>
<xsl:attribute name="test">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">${empty LenovoCodeBase}</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
<c:set var="LenovoCodeBase" scope="request" value="OWv2"/>
</c:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<div role="main" class="mainContent pageWrapper contentContainer">
<div id="privacyWrap">
<!-- beginning of left navigation bar area -->  
<xsl:for-each select="Tab">
<div class="nav-item-header">
<ul>
<li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
<!-- end of left navigation bar area -->
<!-- beginning of content area with anchors -->
<div class="privacyContent"> 
  <xsl:for-each select="ContentText">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="PageTitle" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:attribute name="a-name"><xsl:value-of select="PageTitle"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="PageTitle"/></h1>
  <xsl:value-of select="Content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
<!--End of content area with anchors -->
<!-- beginning of right column bar area -->
<div class="privacyRightColumn">
  <xsl:for-each select="ContentText">
  <xsl:value-of select="Content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<!-- End of right column bar area -->
</div>
</div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my XML:

```
<container name="Privacy" location="Privacy">
<tab name="Navigation">
    <label>Navigation</label>
    <container name="ContentText" location="ContentText" default="1" min="0" max="1">
            <item name="LinkLabel" pathid="LinkLabel">
                <label>Link Label</label>
                <text required="t" maxlength="" />
            </item>
            <item name="URLPath" pathid="URLPath">
                <label>URL Path</label>
                <text required="t" />
            </item>
        </container>        
    </tab>
<tab name="Content">
<label>Content</label>
    <container name="Tab" location="Tab" min="0" max="40" default="1">
    <label>Content Title</label>
        <container name="PageTitle" location="PageTitle" default="0" min="1" max="1">
            <item name="PageTitle" pathid="PageTitle">
                <label>Page Title</label>
                <text required="f" maxlength=""/>
            </item>
        <label>Content</label>
        <container name="Content" location="Content" default="1" min="0" max="40">
            <item name="Content" pathid="Content">
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea external-editor-config="rich-text-area" external-editor="tinymce" rows="4" cols="100"/>
            </item>
        </container>
        </container>    
    </container>        
    </tab>
<tab name="SidebarContent">
    <container name="Sidebar" location="Sidebar">
        <label>Right Sidebar Area</label>
        <container name="sidebarcontent" location="sidebarcontent" min="0" max="4" default="1">
            <label>Content</label>
            <item name="Content" pathid="Content">
                <label>Content</label>
                <description>Content Text</description>
                <textarea external-editor-config="rich-text-area" external-editor="tinymce" rows="4" cols="50"/>
            </item>
        </container>
    </container>        
</tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think it has something to do with the nodes not being matched?

Well, starting from the very beginning:

```
<xsl:template match="Privacy">
```

matches nothing in your input, as there is no element named `Privacy`. I suspect you meant to refer to `container[@name="Privacy"]` ?

Similarly, later you refer to `ContentText` - but that too is an attribute of a `container` element.